# Why does antivirus block my web service?

Tags: .net, apache-flex, web-services, antivirus

I am writing a Flex application that makes web service calls to an ASP.NET web service. I do not have IIS configured, so I run the web service of the Visual Studio development server to test the application.

Everything was going well until I upgraded my AVG antivirus to the latest 2011 edition. Suddenly the web services became inconsistent, with calls failing on the majority of occasions! If I disable AVG, everything works fine.

I cannot figure out why an antivirus should have this effect. I notice others have had similar problems: [.NET Webservice doesn't return JSON data anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763491/net-webservice-doesnt-return-json-data-anymore). Can someone shed light on the matter?

Comment: Maybe you should add an exceptions for your IIS in the firewall (this is just an assumption)

Answer (score 0):

Some antivirus programs provide additional 'internet security' features that block certain kinds of traffic under the assumption that the traffic is malicious.  Your best bet is probably to set up exceptions in the AVG program for all of the process and programs you want to be unaffected by it.

Comment: But this would not be possible in a client machine.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a bug in the AVG's link scanner, it could be messing up the HTTP request or response header. For example, for webservices the correct content-type and encoding are very important and there are also some SOAP-specific headers like SOAPAction.